# How to solve a pep8 Error thrown during a Maven build

Tags: java, python, maven-3

I've been trying to build a work project using maven and it's failing with the following error -

```
"[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:exec (pep8) on project 
xxx_1234: Command execution failed. Cannot run program "pep8" (in directory "C:\workspace\
projects\xxx\xxxx_xxxx\xxx"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified -> [Help 1]".
```

The entire project consists of mainly java code but also contains python and shell scripts.

From what I've gathered from researching this issue, pep8 is a plugin for checking python code for coding standards however, given this project was checked out of gerrit repository and built as needed by other colleagues without issue, my suspicions are that this error is more to do with my own local environment.

Has anybody else come across this error during a maven build or can anybody shed some light on it?

Thanks in advance,

M.

Comment: Do you have python installed on your system? What is the output of `echo %PATH%`?

Comment: Path includes C:\Python35-32\Scripts\;C:\Python35-32\;

Comment: Does running `pep8` in a normal command line window work, or does it give you a command not found error?

Comment: @Crowgrammer pep8 isn't included with Python. Try installing it.

Comment: Installed pep8 and tried mvn clean install again. It failed with the following output:   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:exec (pep8) on project xxxx: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 0):

So this probably means that `pep8` isn't installed. The easiest way to do fix this is install it with `pip`.

```
$ pip install pep8
```

Try running that in a terminal, then your maven build should work just fine.